# Lots of errors with pymysql and Django when trying to run server

Tags: python, mysql, django

I just created a Django project and trying to use virtual environment.
I have successfully installed:

```
 django 1.9.11.
 virtual environment
 python 3.4.4. 
 pymysql
```

I thought I was doing everything right, but I am not able to run django development server and it gives me alot of errors inside files:

```
base.py
__init__.py
connections.py
err.py
```

It gives me this right after I try to run the server:

```
python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors. <locals>.wrapper at 
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

How would i fix this so I can run the development server with mysql?
Thank you.

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
self.connect()
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 268, in get_new_connection
conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 88, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 689, in __init__
self.connect()
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 907, in connect
self._request_authentication()
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1115, in _request_authentication
auth_packet = self._read_packet()




File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 982, in _read_packet
packet.check_error()
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 394, in check_error
err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 120, in raise_mysql_exception
_check_mysql_exception(errinfo)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 115, in _check_mysql_exception
raise InternalError(errno, errorvalue)pymysql.err.InternalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'fundatabase'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))

File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1178, in check
errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1255, in _check_fields
errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 925, in check
errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 208, in check
errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 317, in _check_backend_specific_checks
return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 18, in check_field
field_type = field.db_type(connection)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 625, in db_type
return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 188, in data_types
if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 53, in supports_microsecond_precision
return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 363, in mysql_version
with self.temporary_connection():
```

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py", line 59, in **enter**
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 564, in temporary_connection
    cursor = self.cursor()
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in **exit**
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 268, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/**init**.py", line 88, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 689, in **init**
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 907, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1115, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 982, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 394, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 120, in raise_mysql_exception
    _check_mysql_exception(errinfo)
  File "/Users/me/DjangoProjects/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 115, in _check_mysql_exception
    raise InternalError(errno, errorvalue)
django.db.utils.InternalError: (1049, "Unknown database 'fundatabase'")

From **settings.py**:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'fundatabase',
    'USER' : 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',



}
}
```

Comment: You cut off the error message so it didn't show the traceback.  We need to see that.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the post with the errors

Comment: `Unknown database 'fundatabase'` Post your `settings.py` file, particularly the `DATABASES` section.

Comment: Updated with the database section from settings.py, I didn't touch anything besides that section.

Comment: Are those MySQL settings correct?  Is there a database server running on that host and port, containing a database named `fundatabase` owned by `root`?  Can you access the database via a third-party client using those settings?

Comment: Yes, I am using mysql workbench to check and I am able to access the database and its running. I don't know why it's giving all these other errors too though :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found an answer to this but simply deleted this project and my env which contained django and python. Now I am able to create projects without these errors.